# How to load TIFF image with fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

From what I can tell, fabric.js can only load either JPG or PNG files. It fails when I try to load a TIFF file. Any idea?

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('my_image.tif', function(oImg) {
  canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a problem with FabricJS, but more that browsers in [general does not support the TIFF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support). IE and Safari being exceptions as well as some less mainstream browsers.

## Workarounds

However, it is possible to read and parse TIFF files manually. To read TIFF you can use for example [tiff-js](https://github.com/GPHemsley/tiff-js). You may be able to get plugins for a browser that can decode TIFFs (the latter will possibly require end-user to also install the plugin as well).

Though, I would recommend you to convert TIFF to for example PNG for general use.

Similarly, you will not be able to *save* out TIFF either for the same reasons as above, but feel free to look at my [canvas-to-tiff](https://github.com/epistemex/canvas-to-tiff) solution for that (free).

Comment: link is not dead(canvas-to-tiff)